# Dividing $7$ balls into $5$ baskets and finding the probability each basket has at least 1 ball

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

We are given $7$ balls and $5$ baskets. We want to place each ball into a basket and the probability of each ball assigned to a specific basket is independent of each other. How do we find the probability that there is at least $1$ ball in each basket?

I am aware that we will need to use the inclusion exclusion formula, but how do I find the probabilities?

Let $P(A_i)$ be the probability that the $i^{th}$ basket has an "occupant". We want to find
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) = 1-P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)^c = 1- \bigcup_{i=1}^5 A_i$$

How do I find the probabilities from here?

EDIT: Balls are distinguishable.

Comment: So did you try using P.I.E? Can you show us what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: @Car , we can not answer without checking your attempt. Please show your attempt first !

Comment: What is the total number of ways without restrictions?

Comment: @MathLover it would be $5^7$ am I right? Each ball has 5 different options (baskets) to choose from

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: now apply PIE. Do you know the formula?

Comment: @MathLover PIE is the inclusion-exclusion right? Sorry if this question sounds dumb, I'm new in this field.

Comment: What is the model ? Is it putting *7* identical balls into *5* distinct baskets or a *5* sided die rolled *7* times ?

Comment: It is simply $5^7 - 5 \cdot 4^7 + {5 \choose 2} 3^7 - {5 \choose 3} 2^7 + {5 \choose 4} 1^7$. Check wiki.

Comment: That will give you permutations where none of the boxes are empty. Divide that by total number of permutations.

Comment: I see your edit. But this is a probability question. So you should follow the same approach even if balls were identical.

Comment: @MathLover: If balls were identical, couldn't we simply continue by the method I wrote earlier? That count the solutions to $a_1+\cdots+a_5=7$ under the constraint $a_i\geq 1$ and divide by $5^7$?

Comment: @MathLover The sign alternates because it follows the inclusion exclusion formula am I right?

Comment: @car yes that is correct.

Comment: @LightYagami we should not use stars and bars for probability as the outcomes in stars and bars are not equi-probable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter whether balls are identical or distinct. This is a question on probability and not a question on arrangements. Here we treat balls distinct.

Applying P.I.E, number of arrangements where none of the boxes are empty

$ = 5^7 - 5 \cdot 4^7 + {5 \choose 2} 3^7 - {5 \choose 3} 2^7 + {5 \choose 4} 1^7 = 16800$.

Total number of arrangements without restrictions $ = 5^7$

So the probability $ = \displaystyle \frac{16800}{5^7}$.

Another way to go about it is using Stirling Number of the second kind which will return number of ways to arrange $7$ balls into $5$ indistinguishable groups. You then multiply it by $5!$ as boxes are distinct.

So desired probability $ = \displaystyle \frac{5! \cdot StirlingS2[7,5]}{5^7} = \frac{5! \cdot 140}{5^7}$ which is same as above.

**EDIT:**

While you started with P.I.E which is a more general approach, I wanted to show that you can surely attempt to solve it directly as well given numbers are small.

$7$ balls in $5$ boxes and none of the boxes are empty. So either one of the boxes has $3$ balls or two of the boxes have $2$ balls each. Rest of the boxes will have $1$ ball each.

case $1$: Number of ways to select $3$ balls that are together is $\displaystyle {7 \choose 3} = 35$

case $2$: Number of ways to select two set of $2$ balls is $\displaystyle \ \frac{1}{2} {7 \choose 2} {5 \choose 2} = 105$

Now we assign these groups to boxes by multiplying by $5!$.

So number of permissible arrangements $ =  (105+35) \cdot 5!$. We divide it by $5^7$ to find probability.

Comment: For P.I.E, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#:~:text=In%20a%20very%20abstract%20setting,and%20related%20areas%20of%20mathematics.

Comment: For Stirling number of the second kind, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: I just added one without using general approach in my EDIT.

Comment: Three methods for OP to chew on ! (+1)

Comment: In the P.I.E approach, don't we need to do 1 - $\frac{16800}{5^7}$? Aren't we finding $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) = 1-P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)^c = 1- \bigcup_{i=1}^5 A_i$

Comment: We already did that in the beginning as we started with $5^7 - {5 \choose 1} 4^7...$. See the first term.

Comment: Right. So $\frac{5^7}{5^7}$ gives the 1 in front, and the rest just follows?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: How did we get the ${5 \choose 1} \cdot 4^7 + {5 \choose 2} 3^7 - {5 \choose 3} 2^7$ and so on? I don't quite understand how we got the choose and the ^7 value. I know its form the inclusion exclusion.

Comment: Did you try and read thru the link I sent? We may have to move this to chat as it will take a bit of extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve it is using multinomial coefficients,

there are only $2$ cases to consider

$\dfrac{\dbinom {7}{3,1,1,1,1}\dbinom{5}{1,4} + \dbinom{7}{2,2,1,1,1}\dbinom{5}{2,3}}{5^7}= \dfrac{16800}{5^7}$

Comment: This is indeed another good approach here!

Comment: @MathLover: Glad you like it. Apart from being a routine  method, I like the artistic look of multinomial coefficients !